# CodeIgniter and Wordpress Integration

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, authentication

I have a forum developed with CodeIgniter. And I have my website, powered by Wordpress.

Basically what I'm looking to do is when a user registers on the forums, it adds those details to the Wordpress user table, so they're registered on both.

My code for the forum...

```
/** 
* Create new user record 
* 
* @param    array 
* @param    bool 
* @return    array 
*/ 

// username email password last_ip key 
function create_user($data) 
{ 
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, 
            email, 
            password, 
            last_ip, 
            created, 
            activated 
        ) VALUES ( 
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? 
        )"; 

$this->db->query($sql, array( 
                             $data['username'], 
                             $data['email'], 
                             $data['password'], 
                             $data['last_ip'], 
                             date("Y-m-d H:i:s", utc_time()), 
                             $data['activated'] 
                             )); 

if ($user_id = $this->db->insert_id()) { 
  $this->create_profile($user_id); 
  return TRUE; 
} 
return FALSE; 
} 

function activate_user($username) 
{ 
$this->db->query("UPDATE users SET activated = 1 WHERE username = ?", $username); 
return $this->db->affected_rows(); 
}
```

and the Wordpress register class...

```
/** 
* Handles registering a new user. 
* 
* @param string $user_login User's username for logging in 
* @param string $user_email User's email address to send password and add 
* @return int|WP_Error Either user's ID or error on failure. 
*/ 
function register_new_user( $user_login, $user_email ) { 
$errors = new WP_Error(); 

$sanitized_user_login = sanitize_user( $user_login ); 
$user_email = apply_filters( 'user_registration_email', $user_email ); 

// Check the username 
if ( $sanitized_user_login == '' ) { 
    $errors->add( 'empty_username', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter a username.' ) ); 
} elseif ( ! validate_username( $user_login ) ) { 
    $errors->add( 'invalid_username', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This username is invalid because it uses illegal characters. Please enter a valid username.' ) ); 
    $sanitized_user_login = ''; 
} elseif ( username_exists( $sanitized_user_login ) ) { 
    $errors->add( 'username_exists', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This username is already registered, please choose another one.' ) ); 
} 

// Check the e-mail address 
if ( $user_email == '' ) { 
    $errors->add( 'empty_email', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please type your e-mail address.' ) ); 
} elseif ( ! is_email( $user_email ) ) { 
    $errors->add( 'invalid_email', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The email address isn’t correct.' ) ); 
    $user_email = ''; 
} elseif ( email_exists( $user_email ) ) { 
    $errors->add( 'email_exists', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This email is already registered, please choose another one.' ) ); 
} 

do_action( 'register_post', $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors ); 

$errors = apply_filters( 'registration_errors', $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ); 

if ( $errors->get_error_code() ) 
    return $errors; 

$user_pass = wp_generate_password( 12, false); 
$user_id = wp_create_user( $sanitized_user_login, $user_pass, $user_email ); 
if ( ! $user_id ) { 
    $errors->add( 'registerfail', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Couldn’t register you... please contact the <a href="mailto:%s">webmaster</a> !' ), get_option( 'admin_email' ) ) ); 
    return $errors; 
} 

update_user_option( $user_id, 'default_password_nag', true, true ); //Set up the Password change nag. 

wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $user_pass ); 

return $user_id; 
}
```

I don't need all the extra bumph of the Wordpress class, I'm just looking for a barebones forum values addition to the Wordpress user table.

Any help?

Comment: What's your question? You don't want others to do your work, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Two database configs will be required in your codeigniter config file:

```
$db['wordpress']

$db['default'] //priority
```

To use the wordpress DB assign it a var in your main controller.

```
$this->wordpress_db = $this->load->database('wordpress', TRUE);

//Normal query
$this->db->query();

//wordpress Query
$this->wordpress_db->query();
```

The rest should become obvious